# how do you localize the contents of an UIAlertview

Tags: ios

Using Base Internationalization, It's become really easy to produce automatic localizations based on Object ID. Here's a french version of something.

```
/* Class = "IBUILabel"; text = "Clear Memory"; ObjectID = "fHm-5n-KrF"; */
"fHm-5n-KrF.text" = "Effacer la mémoire";
```

But that only extends to things that Xcode can find in the storyboard.

It should be possible to include text strings in an AlertView. Surely.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Wheel Cicumference" message:@"Ground Trace (mm):" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];

alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
alert.tag = 10;

[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Accept"];
[alert show];
```

Apple docs are vast, and I haven't found anything meaningful so far. I don't necessarily wan't the answer laid out in full for me, Just set me off in the general direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way i know to localize the `UIAlert` is the following:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", @"Error")
                     message:NSLocalizedString(message, message) delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK") otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Comment: If it were not 'OK', let's say it was 'Yes' and the corresponding 'Ja' in German, which would go first? `NSLocalizedString(@"Yes", @"Ja")`? or `NSLocalizedString(@"Ja", @"Yes")`? Thanks.

Comment: after some more research since i posted it's sounding like the old way of doing it programmatically, as opposed to IB mechanisation